# How to handle non-json data and deserialize it in Flutter?

Tags: json, parsing, dart

I'm working on a project in flutter and I'm trying to use an API for CO2 Emissions. The endpoint of the API can be found here: http://www.hqcasanova.com/co2/?callback=callback. I'm having issues parsing the data because it isn't valid JSON notation. Is there a way to handle this inconvenience?

This is the current code I have:

```
 Future<CO2Model> fetchCarbonEmissionData() async {
    var response = await http.get('http://www.hqcasanova.com/co2/?callback=callback/');
    RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"callback\((.*)\)");
    var match = exp.firstMatch(json.encode(response.body));
    print(match.group(0));
    try {
      if(response.statusCode == HTTP_SUCCESS_CODE) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var data = jsonData['callback'];
        CO2Model instance = CO2Model.fromJSON(data);
        return instance;
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Note: Above I tried to use Regular Expressions to deal with this, but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest you use a regex for such a simple task, especially if you sure that you will always get something like

```
callback(...)
```

you could simply trim spaces, and get the substring you want. However, if you want to do it with regex

```
r'callback\((.*).*\)'
```

It basically does what I suggested before, take the match that starts begins with the word *callback* then group the part of the match you want as output (excluding the trailing parenthesis). I hope this helps.

Comment: I like your first solution as well. I got this as the string output: `callback({\"0\":\"416.45\",\"1\":\"412.67\",\"10\":\"391.12\",\"units\":\"ppm\",\"date\":\"2020-04-14T13:01:24+02:00\",\"delta\":5.5,\"all\":\"Up-to-date weekly average CO2 at Mauna Loa\\nWeek starting on April 5, 2020: 416.45 ppm\\nWeekly value from 1 year ago: 412.67 ppm\\nWeekly value from 10 years ago: 391.12 ppm\"})`. How do I extract the following information: "416.5", "412.67", and "391.12"?

Comment: I got it to work by hardcoding numbers when I took the substring of the information. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Simply call replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\\'), ''); on the string you get and you should be done.